# What is the difference between adding the observer to self or to the object?

Tags: ios, swift, key-value-observing

I'm wondering about the difference if I add the observer to self or to the object. So far they have the same effect for KVO.

```
class Human: NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var name: String = "name"
}

class SomeClass: UIViewController {
    @objc var human = Human()

    ...
    override func viewDidLoad() {
     ...

     human.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(Human.name), options: [.old, .new], context: nil)

     addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(human.name), options: [.old, .new], context: nil)
}
```

also does it is the same if I remove the observer using `removeObserver(self)` or `human.removeObserver(self)`?

Appreciate for the answer for this question. Looking forward for it!

Comment: if you do `self.human = Human()` somewhere else in the code I assume the first example will stop working but not the second. I haven't tested it myself though.

Comment: got it! thanks @JoakimDanielson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`human.addObserver(#keyPath(Human.name))` attaches the observer to the value the `human` property has at that time. As Joakim pointed out, if the value of the property changes, then the observer will keep observing the outdated value. And if the previous value deallocates, you might get a nasty crash due to object being deallocated while observers were attached to it.

`addObserver(#keyPath(human.name))` doesn't suffer of the pitfalls of the other approach, and is the recommended approach to registering to observer in case you expect changes to the `human` property. There is one teeny-tiny performance penalty, as Cocoa will also have to intercept the setter for the `human` property, however its unnoticeable.

To sum up, use the first approach only if you're 100% sure that the property won't change over time (i.e. it's declared as `let` and you don't expect any future code changes to make it a `var`). The second approach is more robust and is forward compatible with any future changes related to the lifecycle of the watched property.

Comment: great! Thanks for the answer!